# Web crawling in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, web-crawler, office365-restapi

How to implement **Web Crawling** technology in iOS.
Any reference/ sample program will help. 
Thanks in advance.

**Web Crawling**

A web crawler (also known as a web spider or web robot) is a program or automated script which browses the World Wide Web in a methodical, automated manner. This process is called Web crawling or spidering. Many legitimate sites, in particular search engines, use spidering as a means of providing up-to-date data.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, iOS is not suitable for Web Crawling, because it is not easily flexible for programmers.

But if you want, it is possible. Basically you will use AFNetworking (or Alamofire, or the System default method) to send web requests. Once you get the response, analyze the text, mainly by using Regular Expression. For example, you can write a category for NSString:

```
@implementation NSString(StringRegular)

-(NSMutableArray *)substringByRegular:(NSString *)regular{

    NSString *reg=regular;
    NSRange r = [self rangeOfString:reg options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray array];

    if (r.length != NSNotFound &&r.length != 0) {

        int i=0;

        while (r.length != NSNotFound &&r.length != 0) {

            NSString* substr = [self substringWithRange:r];
            [arr addObject:substr];
            NSRange startr=NSMakeRange(r.location+r.length, [self length]-r.location-r.length);
            r=[self rangeOfString:reg options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:startr];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
@end
```

And then, you will need to store your data. I recommend you to use an online database. If not, you can store the data to your iOS device using FMDatabase or simply SQLite

Comment: and what is *"the System default method"*?

Comment: System default method = NSURLSession & NSURLRequest

Answer (score 0):

I have used [DIFFBOT](https://www.diffbot.com/dev/home/) for web crawling in iOS. The site gives API for different purposes like product, analysing pages or articles. It comes with a free trail of 14 days too. Here is the code for a product web crawling:

```
let url = "https://api.diffbot.com/v3/product?token=YOURTOKEN&url=TheUrlWhichYouwantToSearchinURLENCODEDFORMAT"
let requestUrl = RequestHandlerToken(url: url, withPostMethod: false)
requestUrl.startRequest { (response, error) in
    print(response)
    self.parseData(resp: response)
}
```

The response will be coming in `JSON` format. Make sure that the URL is in `URLencoded` format. Here I am using custom class for hitting the request. You can do this by using `nsurl` session or connection.